# Output all multidimension array, array data from CSV - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a CSV file which the code below uses to put the contents of the CSV into a multidimensional array.

```
<?php

$val = $_GET['articleid'];
//URL Pass STring

$arrCSV = array();
// Open the CSV
if (($handle = fopen("../articles/artlist.csv", "r")) !==FALSE) {                         
// Set the parent array key to 0
$key = 0;
// While there is data available loop through unlimited times (0) using separator (,)
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {
   // Count the total keys in each row
   $c = count($data);
   //Populate the array
   for ($x=0;$x<$c;$x++) {
   $arrCSV[$key][$x] = $data[$x];
   }
   $key++;
} // end while
// Close the CSV file
fclose($handle);
} // end if

?>
```

My first part is to output the entire array.

I think this code below is wrong :(

```
  <?php       
        for ( $row = 1; $row <$arrCSV; $row++ )
            {
        echo ''.$arrCSV[$row]['6'].'';  
            }
    ?>
```

Then I would like it ONLY to output one of the columns [*] [6].

I think I should get here fist before I try the rest.

Any guidance would help.

I am trying to learn, so far I have got this far.

Thank you

Comment: Ok. I need this part..  <?php 
   
 print_r($arrCSV);
   ?>

Comment: Hello, Can anyone help with the code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this not work?:

```
<?php
$val = $_GET['articleid'];
//URL Pass STring

$arrCSV = array();
// Open the CSV
if (($handle = fopen("../articles/artlist.csv", "r")) !==FALSE) {                         

// While there is data available loop through unlimited times (0) using separator (,)
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {
   $arrCSV[] = $data;
} // end while
// Close the CSV file
fclose($handle);
} // end if

?>
```

Comment: This works.. <?php print_r($arrCSV); ?> How can I only out put ONE of the columns.

Comment: Ok, this works. I have changed my code above. Now I need to know how to show ONLY the results based on a column content. e.g. show all the rows id column 6 has RED,

Answer (score 1):

I use this function to convert CSV into an array

```
function csv2array($string, $separatorChar = ',', $enclosureChar = '"', $newlineChar = "\n") 
{
    $array = array();
    $size = strlen($string);
    $columnIndex = 0;
    $rowIndex = 0;
    $fieldValue = "";
    $isEnclosured = False;

    for($i=0; $i<$size;$i++) 
    {
        $char = $string{$i};
        $addChar = "";

        if($isEnclosured) 
        {
            if($char == $enclosureChar) 
            {
                if($i+1<$size && $string{$i+1} == $enclosureChar)
                {
                    $addChar = $char;
                    $i++; 
                }
                else
                {
                    $isEnclosured = false;
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                $addChar=$char;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            if($char==$enclosureChar) 
            {
                $isEnclosured = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                if($char==$separatorChar) 
                {
                    $array[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] = $fieldValue;
                    $fieldValue = "";
                    $columnIndex++;
                }
                elseif($char==$newlineChar) 
                {
                    $array[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] = $fieldValue;
                    $fieldValue="";
                    $columnIndex=0;
                    $rowIndex++;
                }
                else 
                {
                    $addChar=$char;
                }
            }
        }

        if($addChar != "")
        {
            $fieldValue.=$addChar;
        }
    }

    if($fieldValue) 
    {
        $array[$rowIndex][$columnIndex] = $fieldValue;
    }

    return $array;
}
```

You can simply use it like this:

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("../articles/artlist.csv", "r");
$arr = csv2array($handle);

print_r($arr);

?>
```

Comment: The code I have works, I just need to  this part working now. ' $searchchar="cat";
 
 
  for ( $row = 1; $row <sizeof($arrCSV); $row++ )
   {
   { 
    echo ''.$arrCSV[$row]['6'].'';
   }
   }
 ?>'

Comment: I can make it show on column, but I only want to show the rows based on another columns vale. e.g. RED. There are 23 RED's contained in on column, this it should who 23 line.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the solution**

To access you CSV:

```
 <?php

$val = $_GET['articleid'];
//URL Pass STring

$arrCSV = array();
// Open the CSV
if (($handle = fopen("../articles/artlist.csv", "r")) !==FALSE) {                         
// Set the parent array key to 0
$key = 0;
// While there is data available loop through unlimited times (0) using separator (,)
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")) !==FALSE) {
   // Count the total keys in each row
   $c = count($data);
   //Populate the array
   for ($x=0;$x<$c;$x++) {
   $arrCSV[$key][$x] = $data[$x];
   }
   $key++;
} // end while
// Close the CSV file
fclose($handle);
} // end if

?>
```

To display on entire column in the CSV:

```
 <?php       
        for ( $row = 1; $row <$arrCSV; $row++ )
            {
        echo ''.$arrCSV[$row]['6'].'';  
            }
    ?>
```